When you use set path based tkintermapview how can I remove the last points from the path
def update_rival_uavs():
    global rival_markers, initial_set, previous_data, all_routes, uav_routes, colors, konumBilgileri
    # Update rival data
    with open("best_puan.txt", "r") as f:
        best_team_number = int(f.readline().strip())
    with open("takip_eden_iha.txt", "r") as f:
        takip_eden = int(f.readline().strip())

    if konumBilgileri:
        min_lat = min(rival["iha_enlem"] for rival in konumBilgileri)
        max_lat = max(rival["iha_enlem"] for rival in konumBilgileri)
        min_lon = min(rival["iha_boylam"] for rival in konumBilgileri)
        max_lon = max(rival["iha_boylam"] for rival in konumBilgileri)

        if initial_set:
            map_widget.set_position((min_lat + max_lat) / 2, (min_lon + max_lon) / 2)
            map_widget.set_zoom(15)  # Adjust zoom level as needed
            initial_set = False

        for rival in konumBilgileri:
            team_number = rival["takim_numarasi"]
            rival_lat = rival["iha_enlem"]
            rival_lon = rival["iha_boylam"]
            rival_yaw = rival["iha_yonelme"]
            rival_speed = rival["iha_hizi"]
            rival_yuksek = rival["iha_irtifa"]
            rival_time = rival["zaman_farki"]
            low_opacity = rival_time > 15 or rival_yuksek < 5

            # Initialize uav_routes for this team if not already initialized
            if team_number not in uav_routes:
                uav_routes[team_number] = []
                all_routes[team_number] = []
                colors[team_number] = random.choice(["blue", "green", "purple", "orange", "cyan"])

            if (rival_lat, rival_lon, rival_yaw) != previous_data["rival"].get(team_number):
                if team_number in rival_markers:
                    rival_markers[team_number].delete()

                if rival_lat is not None and rival_lon is not None:
                    if team_number == best_team_number:
                        rival_icon = load_and_rotate_uav_icon(rival_yaw, 2, False)
                    elif team_number == takip_eden:
                        rival_icon = load_and_rotate_uav_icon(rival_yaw, 3, False)
                    elif team_number == 13:
                        rival_icon = load_and_rotate_uav_icon(rival_yaw, 4)
                    else:
                        rival_icon = load_and_rotate_uav_icon(rival_yaw, 1, low_opacity=low_opacity)

                    if team_number == 13:
                        rival_marker = map_widget.set_marker(rival_lat, rival_lon, text=f" iha {team_number}\nirtifa: {rival_yuksek}\nhiz: {rival_speed}", icon=rival_icon, command=partial(on_rival_marker_click, team_number))
                    else:
                        rival_marker = map_widget.set_marker(rival_lat, rival_lon, text=f"ravil iha {team_number}\nirtifa: {rival_yuksek}\nhiz: {rival_speed}", icon=rival_icon, command=partial(on_rival_marker_click, team_number))
                    rival_markers[team_number] = rival_marker
                    previous_data["rival"][team_number] = (rival_lat, rival_lon, rival_yaw)

                    uav_routes[team_number].append((rival_lat, rival_lon))
                    all_routes[team_number].append((rival_lat, rival_lon))

                    # Draw rival UAV route
                    if len(uav_routes[team_number]) > 1:
                        ravil_uav_path= map_widget.set_path(uav_routes[team_number], color=colors[team_number], width=2)
                        
                        if len(uav_routes[team_number]) > 5 :
                           # ravil_uav_path.remove_position()
                           # last_position = ravil_uav_path.get_position_list()
                            last = uav_routes[team_number]
                            last[:-2]
                            delete_rival_paths()
                            ravil_uav_path= map_widget.set_path(last, color=colors[team_number], width=2)

def update_map():
    global latest_data, uav_marker, rival_markers, initial_set, previous_data, all_routes, uav_routes, colors, previous_hss_koordinat_bilgileri
    update_rival_uavs()
    root_tk.after(1000, update_map)
update_rival_uavs()

I want to delete a last 2 points from the path when uav is moving. In ma_wiget.py there is
  map_widget.delete_all_path()

This code delete all of the path but I want delete just the last points from the path
When I try to write a funcation in subclass of tkintermapview but It does not bring me together to change and reach the class. After that I try to acsess to canvas_path for remove the point.I call the remove_position but there is erorr in remove becuse remove just take 1 parameter
